# Show dropdowns in Edit Profile (My Sites)

Tags: my-site, my-profile, user-profile

Is it possible to only allow certain values through dropdowns rather than free text when people edit their profile? For instance to limit choice of company, organisation, county or location.

I want to show a 'friendly' name but store the actual value in sharepoint/active directory. Source of names/values could be a list or a database.

If not out of the box, is there a page/control I could edit then it could be possible to add this functionality via JavaScript/jQuery.

**Update (14 Oct 2010):**
I have looked at term store, however it does not show as an option when the type is set to `string (Single Value)`. Also, if you can't use a dropdown, how can you restrict what the user enters? This is important as spelling mistakes can be made when users type and I want to prevent this happening. Hence why I was wondering which master page or control (in the 14 hive I presume) I need to edit to work around this (e.g. replacing the text box with a dropdown via JavaScript).

As well as that, when I do edit a property that allows a term set to be selected, the dropdown just has 'Wiki Categories' in it, repeated about 10 times, but does not appear when I look at the term set. I am a farm administrator, yet can't do anything with the term sets, even after adding myself as an administrator for the Managed Metadata Service application.

Answer (score 1):

There is not "value" versus "display name" option.  Your best bet would be to use the Termstore to provide the lookup/dropdown functionality.  Here is a write-up I did on creating a custom property that uses the Term Store:  http://nextconnect.blogspot.com/2010/06/user-profiles-creating-custom.html

Answer (score 1):

+1 to Mikes suggestion on using term store for this.

For completeness: As an alternative, for example if data should be readily available in an external application, you could use Business Connectivity Service (BCS or formerly BDC just to add to the confusion;-) as a secondary data source for your profiles.

Your data could then be stored in an external database, for example a xRM or ERP system.

To match the two data sources (AD and external DB) you need some unique ID (eg. initials or email).

Comment: Great call.  BCS/BDC is critical for profiles.